# error using placeholders in php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['btnSubmit1'])){
$fullName=htmlentities(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']));
    $emailID=htmlentities(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']));

    $mobNo=htmlentities(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mobile']));
    $c=htmlentities(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['city']));
    $p=htmlentities(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pincode']));
    $t=$_POST['type'];
    $tm=time();



    $query = 'PREPARE statement FROM "INSERT INTO agrl
VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"';
mysql_query($query);
$query = 'SET @name = "$fullName",' .
'@email = "$emailID",' .
'@mobo = "$mobNo",' .
'@city = "$c",' .
'@pincode = "$p",'.
'@country = "$t",'.
'@time = "$tm"';

$query = 'EXECUTE statement USING 
@name,@email,@mobo,@city,@pincode,@country,@time';

    if(!(mysql_query($query))){
        echo "Sorry!!! please try again";
    }
    else{
        $query = 'DEALLOCATE PREPARE statement';
mysql_query($query);
        echo "<script     
type='text/javascript'>alert('success')</script>";



}
}

?>
```

This code works totally f9 but instead of inserting data from form field it inserts variable name
For e.g: if i type robert in name field of my form and hit submit button then instead of saving robert in my databse it saves $fullName..
please help.. thanks in advance

Comment: There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/msqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Comment: Yet even being deprecated, no longer maintained, disregarded and damned, these functions are still part of PHP, up and running.

Answer (score -1):

PHP replace variables with teirs values in string only in two-quoted strings.
Just change quotes in query

```
$query = "SET @name = \"$fullName\"," .
"@email = \"$emailID\"," .
"@mobo = \"$mobNo\"," .
"@city = \"$c\"," .
"@pincode = \"$p\",".
"@country = \"$t\",".
"@time = \"$tm\"";
```

Answer (score -2):

The problem is here:

```
$query = 'SET @name = "$fullName",' .
'@email = "$emailID",' .
'@mobo = "$mobNo",' .
'@city = "$c",' .
'@pincode = "$p",'.
'@country = "$t",'.
'@time = "$tm"';
```

PHP single qutes doesnot allow to you variables inside. Use double quotes instead, or concatenate strings like `'SET @email = "'.$emailID.'",'`

Comment: That is *a* problem, but not *the* problem. *The* problem is that the OP is trying to use prepared statements with a function library that doesn't support prepared statements.

Comment: Have a +1 for helping. Complete bozos giving negative ratings - please refer to my comment above why this answer is okay to me